# Передача параметров функции через файл заголовков

Tags: c++, qt5, ubuntusdk

Имеется UbuntuSDK, Qt5, C++

```
// email_extract.cpp
int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc *> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber)
{
    QFuture<void> f[ThreadNumber];
    for(int i=0; i<ThreadNumber; i++)
    {
        f[i] = run(extract, th_read_vector, docid, nstruc, ThreadNumber);
        f[i].waitForFinished();
    }
    return 0;
}
//headers.h

#ifndef HEADERS_H
#define HEADERS_H

extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);

#endif // HEADERS_H
```

выдаёт ошибки в файле headers.h:

```
error: 'vector' was not declared in this scope
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
 extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);
                                                              ^
error: 'th_read_vector' was not declared in this scope
 extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);
                                                                 ^
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);
                                                                                 ^
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);
                                                                                            ^
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);
                                                                                                        ^
error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 extern int extract_mail_stream(vector<thunderbird_read_struc*> &th_read_vector, int docid, int nstruc, int ThreadNumber);
                                                                                                                        ^
```

Comment: компилятор Вам явно намекает, что он не знает, что такое `thunderbird_read_struc`. Видимо  оно определено в другом файле и Вы забили включить через include.

Comment: структура действительно объявленна в другом файле, подскажите как её красивее вписать в файл заголовков?

Comment: классически - `#include "имяфайл.h"`. Добавить после строки `#define HEADERS_H`

Comment: добавил в этом файле #include <vector> ничего не поменялось. структура объявленна в cpp

Comment: а тогда нужно структуру выносить в отдельный h файл (хотя можно и прям в этот).

Comment: а с остальным как быть? всё что ли там объявлять? как то не очень хорошо получается.

Comment: А никто не говорил, что программировать просто и легко.

Comment: Спору нет., я уже много чего наваял, но в этом, казалось бы не сложном месте, какой то ступор. Ну конечно благодарю за помощь.